# Revoking all permissions from SMB shared folder for others

Tags: permissions, samba, fstab, chmod, cifs

I have a Windows shared folder at a remote computer `storage` which is mounted in my Ubuntu 18.04 system by the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz/folderName /media/data cifs uid=root,username=user,password=pass,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 0 0
```

Everything is good, however, the command `sudo chmod 770 data` does take any effects on the permissions, that is the folder is still in `755` permission.

I come up to this scenario since I am using the remote shared folder as the data folder for nextcloud on Ubuntu.

Comment: try with the `vers` option :: `/media/data cifs _netdev,user,sec=ntml,uid=1000, gid=1000,username=user,password=pass,vers=1.0    0    0` possibles version: `1.0`, `2.02`, `3.1.1` - By the way no need to play with file_mode, dir_mode and so // Since you need NetxCloud to manage it, you may make it available for the NewtCloud running user and tune the `uid` and `gid` according to it // Login and password may not be present in fstab, use a credential file instead

Answer (score 1):

Add another option `nounix` to your list of options:

```
/xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz/folderName /media/data cifs uid=root,username=user,password=pass,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix 0 0
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I always forget to mention the systemd reset commands for this. Once you edit and save fstab run these commands:

```
sudo umount /media/data
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
sudo systemctl restart /media/data
```